# theorem on maximum surface area of cylinder inside sphere

Tags: soft-question, spheres

Some time ago I read about a mathematician who derived this theorem, and still carries it on his TOMB, by question is whether the above theorem that states-

> the maximum surface area of a cylinder inside a sphere is equal to that of the surface area of the sphere itself!

Comment: where can we find a graphic of this problem?

Comment: that's the reason i want to verify whether I am correct

Comment: this video says its half the surface area of the sphere ? but as far as I remember I read about equality
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Du2Y4x_hQY8